# I am following an Opencv tutorial but I am not sure of the purpose of cv2.absdiff(frame1, frame2), what is the purpose of this?

Tags: python, windows, opencv, computer-vision

(Beginner)
Here is the code:

```
    import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('vtest.avi')

ret, frame1 = cap.read()
ret, frame2 = cap.read()


while cap.isOpened():
    diff = cv2.absdiff(frame1, frame2)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(diff, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), 0)
    _, thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 20, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=3)
    contour, _ = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    cv2.drawContours(frame1, contour, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)


    cv2.imshow('feed', frame1)

    frame1 = frame2
    ret, frame2 = cap.read()


    if cv2.waitKey(40) == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

What is the point of cv2.absdiff(frame1, frame2)? Aren't frame1 and frame2 the same? Also, what is the purpose of frame1 = frame2?

The result can be seen at 5:35:01 of this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N81PCpADwKQ&t=945s)

Answer (score 0):

`cv2.absdiff(frame1, frame2)` is used to compare two frames, current frame with previous one. You can get refrence from here: http://www.robindavid.fr/opencv-tutorial/chapter10-movement-detection-with-background.html

`frame1 = frame2` are not same at this stage.

Comment: why are frame 1 and frame2 different? Is it because frame1 was assigned to cap.read() before frame 2.

Comment: Its a while loop and motion frame converting from current to previous.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If I comment out the entire while loop and then show frame1 and frame2, they are different. Why is this?